# Facebook custom actions wording... Is it possible to add words before the `on`, `via` etc

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebooks graph API to post actions to a users profile depending on what they do on my site (Login, Register, Watch a Video & Rate a video).

When a user rates a video, I currently have it say:

*User* rated *link_to_video* on *website/app_name*

I would like it to say:

*User* rated *link_to_video* **5 stars** on *website/app_name*

Notice the `5 Stars` in the above post.

Is this possible or am I wasting my time searching for an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add 5 starts to your title

```
<meta property="og:title" content="LINK_TO_VIDEO 5 stars" />
```

yes, it will be shown as a part of your link, but I don't think it matters a lot

Another idea is to create five (or whatever your number of maximal stars is) actions which are named

- rated 5 stars
- rated 4 stars
- rated 3 stars
- rated 2 stars
- rated 1 star

Comment: That will work, but please don't do that, it'll make your aggregations and the users news feed look very strange - you should include the 'rating' / stars as a parameter of the action itself

Comment: @igy i didnt like the idea of doing this either,  bit how do I add the parameter of the action itself?

Comment: @just I added an idea to my answer

Comment: @Just so what did you use instead?

Comment: @Just why is it a problem to create more objects (objects)?